# How to add .so files in android library module

Tags: android, java-native-interface, .so

I am making two applications i am creating a library to add in both the applications,but here apps need .so files,if i try to add in app/jnilibs it is working fine but in common library if i add .so files in jnilibs i am facing issue.

```
  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader[DexPathList,nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.next.app-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.next.app-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "extensionloader.so"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this link given below it works fine for my issue

https://gist.github.com/khernyo/4226923#comment-812526

for gradle android plugin v0.3 use

```
 "com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication"
```